# Language with dynamic store and calculation of variables

Tags: variables, dynamic, storage, julia

I work with computational geometry in C++. In particular I calculate properties of a triangulation with moving vertices. For optimization purposes I end up considering an interface design for the triangles where a property is re-calculated only when needed, i.e. when a vertex of the triangle has been moved, but otherwise is retrieved from stored memory.

I recently watched videos on the Julia programming language and was introduced to JIT thinking. I am now wondering if this above mentioned type of design pattern is built-in in any popular (preferably scientific) languages. As I envision it, one would register variables to listen to changes in some fields and depending on the activity of these fields, as the variable is used, the value is retrieved or calculated on the fly. All under the hood. Has something similar to this been done?

Comment: This sounds like reactive programming, and there is React.jl package, but it's not really intended for performance but rather for implementing interactive user interfaces.

Comment: Thank you Stefan for giving me a term. I've encountered this pattern with MVC as well, but more relevantly I found that something similar is central to the workings of constraint programming -- in waking propagators only when relevant domain ranges have been pruned. By that note, has the Julia community looked into constraint programming?

Comment: If you're interested in constrained optimization, then http://www.juliaopt.org/ is where you want to look. If you mean Prolog-style programming, then no, that hasn't to my knowledge been extensively explored.